# OpenVPN tunnel routing issues

Tags: vpn, openvpn, site-to-site-vpn

Please excuse my inexperience. I managed to setup a vpn connection between a single client and server. Currently I am testing this in VM's which are running Server 2008 R2 (temporary since I have install disks handy). Each VM is in a remote location with its own IP address. (I am remoting in).

What is happening is that I am able to ping the VPN Server from the client with no problem. once I attempt to ping another device on the network (say server is 192.168.1.2 and other device is 192.168.1.3) i am getting request timed out. The tracert has the packet being routed through the VPN to the Virtual Gateway of 10.8.0.1. Also I am not able to ping from the server to the client. ie ping 192.168.2.3

Below is a simple topology.

[Network 1] Hosts server on 192.168.1.2
192.168.1.0 | 255.255.255.0

[Network 2] client on 192.168.2.3
192.168.2.0 | 255.255.255.0

[VPN Server] 10.8.0.1
10.8.0.0 | 255.255.255.0

So essentially from running tracert on client side I am getting...

1 30ms 40ms 20ms HOME [10.8.0.1]

2 *    *    *    Request timed out.

etc...

Meaning the packet is reaching the server but not being routed from server to machine on same network.

I realize there could be several problems so even a direction would be greatly appreciated. The openvpn logs are just showing ipv6 routing warnings but I am not using ipv6 so i am assuming this can be ignored.

I used this tutorial to setup the server and client
http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/security/security-howto/30353-how-to-set-up-a-site-to-site-vpn-with-openvpn?showall=&start=1

Comment: Is packet forwarding turned on?  I'm not sure how one would do this in Windows.

Comment: Its likely i didn't setup my routs correctly i guess that's how packet forwarding is handled. I'm going to double check right now

Comment: I double checked my routes and I am still not certain where the problem lies. any ideas?

Comment: Did you enable Forwarding? http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2008/11/20/balancing-act-dual-nic-configuration-with-windows-server-2008-nlb-clusters.aspx basically the registry change for IpEnableRouter.

Comment: It Finally works! Thank you CJC, I did do that earlier and it still did not work. What I did was essentially removed all old config files and redid my setup following this tutorial which is centered around windows vs linux... http://www.runpcrun.com/howtoopenvpn . I had to delete my previously set routes ( i just ran route -f which deletes all routes [don't do this on a production server] and then openvpn setup the routes for me which I specified in the .ovpn file. ). After making sure my router is pointing all the packets for the tunnel to the openVPN server I was able to ping my clients.